# Java Weka split instances by attributes

Tags: java, machine-learning, split, weka

I have the following dataset:

```
Instances trainingSet = loadData("wind_training.txt");
```

I want to split the `trainingSet` into `trainingSet_X` and `trainingSet_y`, such that both will be of type `Instances`.
I want of course that `trainingSet_X` will include all attributes excluding the target attribute, and `trainingSet_y` will include only the target attribute.

I tried to do it the naive way - creating 2 copies of `trainingSet`, and deleting the attributes I don't want from each, but turns out I can't delete class attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve your problem is to define that there is no class attribute in your `Instances` object:

```
trainingSet_X.setClassIndex(-1); // -1 or any other negative number
```

Now you can remove the attribute without getting an exception.